# 'Failed to process features.' error from Google Vision API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, computer-vision, ocr, google-cloud-vision

Sometimes https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate request returns strange error: "Failed to process features." What does it mean? The issue is very rare. The most requests are succeeded.

I did not find any specific in failed requests. I tried to reproduce the issue by sending incorrect requests (bad type instead of "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION", empty "features" section and etc.) But error message is not "Failed to process features." in that cases.

Request body:

```
  {
    requests: [
      {
        image: {
          content: <base64 encoded PNG file>
        },
        features: [
          { type: "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Image is small: 480x18px, 3514 bytes. Request execution time is normal (~300 ms).

Comment: Is there an image that always fails for you or does the same image sometimes fail and sometimes succeed?

Comment: Looks like it is random issue. The same image can be recognized or not. But I am not 100% sure. Our service does not collect user`s images. But user can confuse something.

Comment: If you come across one of your own example image where it happens, it would help. It's not related to the type passed in eg "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"

Comment: Hi again. I slightly modified the code to repeat recognition after several second if the error occurs. Also I stored the problem images. So we have the next statistics for the last week:
1. 4 cases
2. Trick with repeat recognition isn't work, second attempt is also finished with the same error
3. Recognition works fine while analyzing (I can't reproduce the issue with stored images)

Comment: So a second attempt right after the first attempt with the same image, you get the error again. Then you store that same image. When you manually try that stored image several hours later, it works. Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Exactly. I can't at now reproduce the issue with the stored "problem" images. It looks like the images aren't cause...